# Using helper arguments and template keyword arguments at the same time

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have a template `taskList` that receives a list of tasks and an options hash as arguments like this:

```
{{> taskList tasks=taskHelper options=listOptions}}
```

In this case, the `taskHelper` returns all existing tasks. **Is it possible to pass arguments to the `taskHelper` in this scenario?** For example, if I want to show only *done* tasks in the template, I would like to do something like this:

```
{{> taskList tasks=taskHelper 'done' options=listOptions}}
```

That won't work because the template compiler doesn't treat `'done'` as argument for the helper but as a non-keyword argument for the template, resulting in this error message:

```
Can't have a non-keyword argument after a keyword argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**meteor < 1.1.1**

You can make it work without any changes to your helpers by doing this:

```
{{#with taskHelper 'done'}}
  {{> taskList tasks=this options=listOptions}}
{{/with}}
```

**meteor >= 1.1.1**

[Nested helper expressions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/4101) should solve this problem:

```
{{> taskList tasks=(taskHelper 'done') options=listOptions}}
```

Comment: Thanks! The second version is what I tried first, so I'm looking forward to 1.1.1. :)

Comment: Wow! Eventually we can get rid of all these terrible {{#with}}! Thanks for your answer.