# Meteor #each @index passed to Dynamic Template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to pass down the index of an item from an `{{#each}}` loop into a dynamic template, but am lost on how to get it there (in a clean way).

Current code:

```
{{#each item}}
{{Template.dynamic template=type data=this}}
{{/each}}
```

With this, `{{@index}}` is not accessible in the dynamically loaded template.

I also tried using a template helper, but it doesn't appear the index is tracked in the context.

```
{{#each item}}
{{Template.dynamic template=type data=itemData}}
{{/each}}

Template.items.helpers({
  itemData() {
    // can't access index in here
    return this;
  }
});
```

Can anyone advise on how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this using the following pattern:

```
... Template.Items
{{#each items}}
{{>Template.dynamic itemConfig @index}}
{{/each}}

Template.items.helpers({
  itemConfig(index) {
    const data = this;
    data.index = index;

    return {
      data,
      template: this.type //this.type is where im storing my template name
    };
  },
});
```

Using the @index as a helper param, and then Blaze uses the object as a config for the dynamic template!

:)

**EDIT:** I found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441032/using-helper-arguments-and-template-keyword-arguments-at-the-same-time). Does the same job, and I prefer how it looks.

```
{{>Template.dynamic template=type data=(templateData @index)}}
```

Where `templateData` is essentially the same helper from before but just returns `data` with an `index` prop.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each item}}
{{Template.dynamic template=type index=@index}}
{{/each}}
```

You can use 'index' in dynamic template to access index